# Kali Linux and Win 7 dual boot, I want to change the active partition and bootloader, not sure in what order

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I created a partition for Kali Linux and a Live USB. I used the Live USB, was intrigued by what I saw ( first time ever seeing Linux ) and chose to install but the install wouldn't complete.

Several attempts failed, so I thought maybe something was wrong with the USB but when I rebooted I got nothing , like my hard drive was gone.

I booted back into the USB and after running through the install process again I got Kali up and running. Rebooting then took me straight into Kali, but F5 takes me into GRUB boot screen and I can choose to boot into Win 7 from there.

Looking at my disk management from Win shows that my Linux partition is now my active drive.

This is my question :
If I make Win partition my active drive again do I have to repair/replace the bootloader first? What I would really like is for the boot options to appear automatically when I turn on or restart and if that is not possible I would like Win 7 to be the automatic go to.

Another question :
Is there a way to have Win bootloader initialize first then upon choosing Linux drive the grub loader initializes?

I'm very new to Linux and bootloaders, and am trying to absorb all I can.

Can anyone shine some light?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a menu to appear on restart, and default to booting Windows, then your best best is to leave the active partition where it is (pointing to GRUB), and simply change the default setting in the GRUB configuration.

You didn't say which version of GRUB you are using, and the instructions vary quite a lot between GRUB 1 and GRUB 2.

While it is possible to set up chainloading from the Windows boot loader to GRUB, that would be far more complicated than just changing the timeout and default selection in your already-working GRUB setup.

Comment: How do I check the GRUB version? Should I restart and go to it? I know that when I press F5 it says something like loading GRUB then the boot options and KALI LINUX at the top...

Comment: Yes, inside the GRUB menu I suspect the version number will be listed somewhere.  Problem is that GRUB 2 is *extremely* reconfigurable, so there's not one single key combination that will show you bootloader information on all configurations.  Does it look something like http://www.digitendency.com/2014/11/how-to-change-boot-order-in-linux-kali.html ?

Comment: @disk_Error: Actually, you may just be able to follow the instructions here: http://www.sajeeva.net/articles/change-default-boot-order-grub-kali-linux-dual-boot-system/